# Using custom CSS styles in item Templates

Tags: javascript, extjs, mobile, sencha-touch-2

I have a dataview that load some data from a Store, like this example:

```
{
            xtype: 'dataview',

            store: {
                data : [
                    {name: 'nota_fiscal.pdf', type : 'Nota fiscal', url : 'http://teste'},
                    {name: 'doc_veiculo.pdf', type : 'Documento do Veículo', url : 'http://teste'},
                ]
            },

            itemTpl: '<div style="background-color: white; margin: 10px; padding: 10px">' +
            '<span>{name}</span>' +
            '<span style=" float: right;">{type}</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div>' +
            '<a class="btn">Download</a>' +
            '</div>'
}
```

I need to known a way to define a custom css and make it accessible inside item template. In the example I want to define a css to 'btn' link class.

Comment: So you want to write css for the class `.btn` in a scss file, and you want to know where to put that file and how to include it? I'm not sure what you want to accomplish..

Comment: I defined class btn in resource/sass/app.scss file, but it doens't work. I mean, the style had not affect on item template.

Comment: What did you do already? Did you build/compile the app again? What happens if you run the command `sencha ant sass` from within the app folder? Do you find the class in app.css?

Comment: try to inspect your page, trace your button, see what class or style the button have, maybe the button have style from extjs and overwrite it.

Comment: what is your extjs version?